# Creating a unique constraint with SQL Server, MySQL databases

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, unique-constraint

How do you create a unique constraint in SQL Server or MySQL. For example, I have a 'Customer' table that has 'CustomerID' as a primary key. If I want the 'CustomerCode' to be unique(i.e. no duplicates), how do I configure this in the SQL Server studio 2008?

Comment: What's so hard looking this up in the manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD CONSTRAINT U_CustomerCode UNIQUE(CustomerCode)
```

Comment: Thank you very much,this worked well and only got an error when I ran because I already had duplicate data in my column.